# Firebase Authentication hangs when app offline

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have a web application using Firebase authentication part of the Firebase SDK 9.20.0 with FirebaseUI 6.0.2, and I have issues with the authentication part when connectivity is bad.

- Everything works as expected when internet is good: user can log in and as persitence is enabled, they dont need to input their credentials again when logging back in after they have left the app.
- When there is no internet it workds great too: the app will log the user in almost instantly, using the persisted credentials.
- But when the connectivity is bad, logging back in will take ages and it is like the app waits for a timeout to happen before letting the user in.

I am guessing that when there is no connectivity at all it will directly use the persisted data but when it detects some connectivity, it will try using to detect any changes server-side and will only fail when a timeout is triggered.

Is there a way to reduce or bypass this timeout?

Here is the code I use to initialize Firebase Auth and FIrebase UI

```
// Firebase core
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
const firebaseapp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, projectId, storageBucket, messagingSenderId, appId, measurementId
});

// App-check
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from "firebase/app-check";
initializeAppCheck(firebaseapp, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(process.env.VUE_APP_reCAPTCHAPublicKey),

  // Optional argument. If true, the SDK automatically refreshes App Check tokens as needed.
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
});

// Auth + FirebaseUI
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
const auth = getAuth(firebaseapp);
const b_ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);
const b_uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '',
    signInOptions: [ { provider: EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID } ],
    'credentialHelper': firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE //to avoid showing credentialhelper
};
b_ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", b_uiConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enabling persistence for Firestore, but not for Firebase authentication. You can enable persistence for Firebase authentication by adding the setPersistence() method.

By adding the auth.setPersistence() method with the firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL argument, you are telling Firebase to store the user's authentication state locally on the device. This means that even if the user closes the app and reopens it later, their authentication state will still be persisted and they won't need to log in again.

Add the following line:

```
// Enable persistence for Firebase authentication
auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
```

before:

```
b_ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", b_uiConfig);
```

Comment: From the documentation on [auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence): "For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser." So setting the persistence explicitly should not be needed in most cases.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. Persistence is enabled as when app is offline logging works great. The issue only occurs when conncetivity exists but is really poor

Comment: I have tried manually enabling persistence like you mention and it has no impact